# Is it possible to change pagination permalinks in WP?

Tags: wordpress

The default link for pagination looks like "site.com/articles/page/2", but I need to do the page number as parameter(example: "site.com/articles?page=2"). I've tried to use add_filter function:

```
add_filter('get_pagenum_link', 'edit_paginate_url'); 
    function edit_paginate_url($url){ 
    $pagenum = preg_match("/\/\d\//", $url, $pagenum); 
    $pagenum = preg_replace("/\//", "", $pagenum); 
    $url = preg_replace("/\/page\/\d/", "?page=", $url); 
    return $url . $pagenum; 
}
```

But it didn't work. It returns url like: "site.com/articles0/page/2/" (this filter only adds zero symbol before pagination part of url).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the below url in which you have to set `base` and `format` as per your requirements.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to search reference of function(the_posts_pagination) and found nothing better then filter. But this solution much easier. Thanks a lot.